# ajax form is not sending headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so when I'm submitting my form I'm not getting any header data. I've done this type of submission a billion times (figuratively of course), but still there's always the possibility I'm missing something. Thoughts? Code below:

```
$('#app-submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        validate();
        var data = [];
        var required = [];
        var questions = [];
        var errors = 0;
        $('#application-form :input:not(:radio):not(:button)').each(function(){
            name = $(this).attr('id');
            val = $(this).val();
            data[name] = val;
            if($(this).closest('div').hasClass('has-error')){
                errors++;
            }
        });

        $('#application-form .not-empty').each(function(){
            name = $(this).attr('id');
            val= $(this).val();
            required[name] = val;
        });

        for(var i = 1; i < 12; i++){
            name = 'q'+i;
            val = $('input[name="q'+i+'"]:checked').val();
            if($('input[name="q'+i+'"]').closest('div').hasClass('has-error')){
                errors++;
            }
            questions[name] = val;
        }

        if(!errors){
            $.ajax({
                url : 'assets/server/submitApp.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data : data,
                dataType : 'JSON',
                success : function(data){
                    if(!data.errors){
                        $('#application-holder').html(data.message);
                    }else{
                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

NOTES:
The HTTP headers are not showing up in the console, and just to verify that I'm not getting data, I did a `var_dump($_REQUEST)` and it shows null as well

UPDATES: I have edited the code to just submit one of the arrays that I have build, and it still is not sending any data. event though before I submit the ajax call, if I place a console.log(data) it will show that the array is indeed filled with data.

Comment: What header data is not being sent? How are you testing for it?

Comment: What do you mean you're not seeing header data? Your server is getting the request from the client but you're not seeing HTTP headers? What are you seeing? What does your PHP log say?

Comment: I'm not getting and http data and var_dump on php registers nothing

Comment: How can you tell that `var_dump($_REQUEST)` returns `null`? How are you looking at it? What does `$_REQUEST` has to do with headers?

Comment: okay I think I might have some teminology mixed up. The header data I'm referring to, is not the `header()` function for php, but the literal header data sent from the client form to the server script that I am running. Found on the `url:` option i the `$.ajax` call. `$_REQUEST` is going to tell me what data is received by my script from the submission, I also run a `var_dump` generally so that I can see the structure of what I am working with so that I manage my data correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array to `data`.

If you do this then the array must contain, using standard numerical indexes, a series of objects with `name` and `value` properties.

You aren't doing that.

The only time you modify the array is to add named properties to it as if it were a plain object.

Use a plain object in the first place.

```
var data = [];
```

should be:

```
var data = {};
```

Objects are expected to have named properties. Arrays are not, they are for sequential data.

Comment: I'm going to make sure to take notes this time, because I think i've done this before! Thank you very much for your assistance.